# Adding columns one by one to a new DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

For a new `pandas` `DataFrame`:

```
In [3]:    import pandas as pd
           dfo = pd.DataFrame() 
   ...:    dfo['filename'] = 'file1.csv'
```

What are its columns?

```
In [4]: dfo.columns                                                                                                                                                                     
Out[4]: Index(['filename'], dtype='object')
```

That looks OK.  What about the "row" that was added (with value `file1.csv`) ?

```
In [5]: len(dfo)                                                                                                                                                                        
Out[5]: 0
```

*Not* so good..   So what happened here?  How should that column value be added: can it be done similarly to the original attempt or do we need separate commands?

My motivation is that the set of columns is determined dynamically and it fits this particular use case better to do one at a time instead of in bulk like I typically do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input should be a list

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['filename'] = ['hhh.xlsx']
```

and the dataframe will be

```
In[1]:print(len(df))
Out[1]:1
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: yes! thanks that's what i needed.  Would be nice if there were some warning or error if data is thrown away and/or code ignored